# Outlook crashes after throwing "Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain." exception

Tags: c#, vsto, enterprise-library, outlook-addin

I've developed a outlook addin with c# 3.5, VSTO and Visual Studio 2008 for Outlook 2003.

The code works fine almost all time but sometimes Outlook crashes after throwing "Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain." exception

Exception stackTrace:

```
03/17/2011 8:17:05 AM : DoSomething_Outlook_Startup: 
      exception:The current build operation (build key Build 
      Key[Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionPolicyImpl, DoSomething Notify Policy]) 
      failed: Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain. 
      (Strategy type ConfiguredObjectStrategy, index 2)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionPolicy.GetExceptionPolicy(Exception exception, String policyName, ExceptionPolicyFactory factory)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionPolicy.HandleException(Exception exceptionToHandle, String policyName, ExceptionPolicyFactory policyFactory)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionPolicy.HandleException(Exception exceptionToHandle, String policyName)
   at DoSomething.OutlookAddIn.DoSomething_Outlook.PaintMainMenu(Application objApp)
   at DoSomething.OutlookAddIn.DoSomething_Outlook.DomeSomething_Outlook_Startup(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Outlook Addin Code:

```
//Startup handler
private void DoSomeThing_Outlook_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                applicationObject = this.Application;
..
..
..
                    PaintMainMenu(applicationObject);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
        //Exception being thrown from PaintMainMenu is handled here
        //
                Logger.Log("DoSomething_Outlook_Startup: exception:" + ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }

//Method to add DoSomething menu item to File menu
private void PaintMainMenu(Outlook.Application objApp)
{
            try
            {

                objApp.ActiveExplorer().CommandBars["File"].Reset();


                menubar = objApp.ActiveExplorer().CommandBars.ActiveMenuBar;
                Office.CommandBarPopup cbc = (Office.CommandBarPopup)
                           menubar.FindControl
                           (Office.MsoControlType.msoControlPopup, 30002, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);

                if ((menubar != null))
                {
                    _DoSomething = (Office.CommandBarButton)cbc.Controls.Add(
                                 Office.MsoControlType.msoControlButton, Missing.Value,
                                 Missing.Value, 6, true);

                    if (_DoSomething != null)
                    {
                        _DoSomething.Tag = AddInConstants.C_Menubar_Menu_Tag;
                        _DoSomething.Caption = AddInConstants.C_Menubar_Menu_Caption;

                        _DoSomething.Click += new _CommandBarButtonEvents_ClickEventHandler(DoSomething_Click);
            _DoSomething.Enabled = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
  //below line throws "Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain."
                bool rethrow = ExceptionPolicy.HandleException(ex, AddInConstants.C_Global_NotifyPolicy);
                if (rethrow)
                    throw;
            }
}
```

Thanks in advance,
Hemant

Comment: Just curious: what is the original exception that you are trying to handle?

Comment: any kind of exception. Actually the PaintMainMenu throws an exception and the catch section in this function catches and passes to Enterprise Library's ExceptionPolicy.HandleException to handle according to the policy defined in configuration. but it (i.e. Enterprise Library) throws the "Access to unloaded appdomain" exception which is, then, catch by caller function i.e. DoSomeThing_Outlook_Startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probabaly a race condition.

You are trying to add something to the Outlook menu. If your code runs before the menu has loaded, you will get this error.

You could try putting a wait in your code, so that you are sure that the menu is loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the hlep. But if the menu item raises an exception the enterprise library should be able to handle it. The exception here talks about unloaded domain from enterprise library's class. The default domain is not unloaded because the statement Logger.Log was able to execute.  But i'll give it a try. Thanks again